# Getting Error when downgrading NPM version

Tags: node.js, npm

Tried updating NPM version for some dependencies now, I need to downgrade to older version but I m unable to do so.

Current NPM version: npm v9.8.1

`ERROR: npm v9.8.1 is known not to run on Node.js v12.22.11.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: ^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0. You can find the latest version at` [`https://nodejs.org/`](https://nodejs.org/)`.`

Comment: It's better to manage both node and npm using `nvm`

Answer (score 2):

Your Node.js version is incompatible with the NPM version, this is stated in the error.
Downgrade Node.js version via NVM, this will also downgrade NPM to the corresponding version.

```
nvm use 12
```

Comment: Error nvm : The term 'nvm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the official Nodejs for download the node version 12 or install this  [`Node version manager`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for control the version easier

Comment: Even tried installing higher version but still we are getting same error